# Как задать переменную окружения в GEM (pHash)

Tags: ruby, gems

Я на OS X установил [pHash gem](https://github.com/toy/pHash)

Когда я использую библиотеку выдает сообщение : `Could not open library 'libpHash.dylib'`

В документации сказано: `You can specify path to pHash library explicitly using environment variable like PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib.`

Я пробовал запускать с таким параметром , но без результата `PHASH_LIB=/opt/local/lib/libpHash.dylib ruby program.rb`

Как это можно исправить?
Либо как еще можно использовать perceptual hash в Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гем pHash был архивирован автором несколько недель назад.

Рекомендую использовать мой гем [dhash-vips](https://github.com/Nakilon/dhash-vips), реализующий алгоритм dhash, а также мой усовершенствованный вариант -- idhash, суть которого описана в README репозитория.

Сейчас я занимаюсь переводом функции сравнения хешей с Ruby на C -- должна стать быстрей раз в 25. Тогда, согласно моим бенчмаркам, гем станет лучшим в своем деле.